# AMP Pages not getting tracked in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

We converted our two modules into an AMP and everything was going good all pages were getting tracked in Analytics, but suddenly from yesterday(23-Jan-2018) around 9.30am EST AMP pages are not getting tracked in Analytics.

We are using GTM script to track our pages and it placed correctly.

Ads Impression was increased yesterday, but total page views is less.

Even i have checked webmaster tool and we do not have any issues
[image]

Please let me know what can be done to bring it back

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The error is came from amp-analytics. That PR is rolled back and everything will fine soon. But not now, the error is still here.

Issue on Github: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/13005

### Update

Everything is OK now. This error is not only affect Analytics. but also all of your code in GTM for AMP stopped working for 23 hours. That's long long day.